# How to pass xcode project name with spaces in sonar-project.properties file

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I want to run sonarqube scanning on xcode project using run-sonar-swift.sh script. My xcode project name is **Temperature Converter**.
But when I provide this name it takes only **Converter** and not full name in **sonar.swift.project** field.
How to provide project name having spaces to sonar-project.properties.

Answer (score 0):

place the value between quotation marks.
sonar.projectName="Temperature Converter"

Comment: I am talking about sonar.swift.project=Temperature Converter.xcodeproj

Comment: @abhishek gaikwad Ok, but have you tried using the quotes?

Comment: yes its taking just **Converter** and not the whole project name.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so my project had a whitespace in its name.

I tried everything for the `sonar.sources` variable:

`sonar.sources=My Project`
`sonar.sources="My Project"`
`sonar.sources='My Project'`
`sonar.sources=My\ Project`

Always getting the following error:
`The domain/default pair of (.../src/My, Project/Info.plist) does not exist`
with this comma just before the whitespace.

I know I don't answer the question, but I think the best solution is to remove the whitespace from your project :)

It appeared to be very easy. In 3 steps :

1. Click on your project name on left panel (first element), Then first tab of right panel => Identity and Type => Name, change the name by removing the whitespace
2. Just under the Name you changed, check that Location is "Relative to Group", then go to left panel, just under the project name you will find the sources root folder (which still have the whitespace). Remove the whitespace from it.
3. Go in your project settings, and search "My Project" (replace with yours, of course), and remove the whitespace from each entry (only the one that corresponds to the source root folder. No need to remove the one in `My Project-Bridging-Header.h` for example)

Clean and compile. It should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

If you [URL-encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the project or group name, it should be recognised by the Sonar API.

For example if your SonarQube user group name is `Test Project 001` you can delete it as follows:

```
/api/user_groups/delete?name=Test%20Project%20001"
```

With curl:

```
curl -u ${MYTOKEN}: -i -X POST "http://localhost:9000/api/user_groups/delete?name=Test%20Project%20001"
```